# BigQuery Union Distinct Where Value not in Preceding DataSet

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, union

I am trying to reconcile some student database with GSuite emails, where usernames have been created inconsistently for years.

The gist of the query I am trying to make on BigQuery is:

1. Match Emails to Students from email Pattern 1 and union with
2. Match Emails to Students from email Pattern 2 and union with
3. Emails not in 1 an 2.

Or in SQL:

```
with mymatches as (
    with emaildataset as (
        select 'testA' as col
        union all
        select 'testB'
        union all
        select 'testC'
        union all
        select 'testD'

    )

    select * from emaildataset where col like '%A'
    union distinct
    select * from emaildataset where col like '%B'
),

emaildataset2 as (
        select 'testA' as col
        union all
        select 'testB'
        union all
        select 'testC'
        union all
        select 'testD'
)

select * from mymatches

union distinct

select * from emaildataset2 where emaildataset2.col not in (select col from mymatches)
```

This runs happily, but when I run the real code, then I'm getting duplicates.

The real code is now:

```
with matchedEmails as (
    with g as (
        select * from gsuite.StudentUsers
        union all
        select * from gsuite.AlumniUsers
    )

    select
    std.STDCODE,
    g.*

    from g
    inner join quick.all_students_alumni as std
    on split(lower(g.Email), '@')[offset(0)] = split(quick.studentEmail(std.FNAME, std.MNAME, std.LNAME, std.STATUSTYPE), '@')[offset(0)]

    where g.OU like '/Student%' or OU like '/Alumni%'

    union distinct select
    std.STDCODE,
    g.*

    from g
    inner join quick.all_students_alumni as std
    on split(lower(g.Email), '@')[offset(0)] = split(quick.studentEmail(std.FNAME, '', std.LNAME, std.STATUSTYPE), '@')[offset(0)]

    where g.OU like '/Student%' or OU like '/Alumni%'

)

select * from matchedEmails

union distinct select

'NOT MATCHED' as STDCODE,
g.*

from (
    select * from gsuite.StudentUsers
    union all
    select * from gsuite.AlumniUsers
) as g

where g.Email not in (select Email from matchedEmails)
and g.OU like '/Student%' or OU like '/Alumni%'
```

As a result though, I am getting duplicates in the Email column, which--based on my knowledge and test above--should not be, due to the `where g.Email not in (select Email from matchedEmails)` clause.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, very last WHERE clause should be fixed to look like below

```
where g.Email not in (select Email from matchedEmails)
and (g.OU like '/Student%' or OU like '/Alumni%')
```

As you can see  - the brackets around `g.OU like '/Student%' or OU like '/Alumni%'` were missing

it might be something else too that still need to be fixed - but this answers you below questions

> As a result though, I am getting duplicates in the Email column, which--based on my knowledge and test above--should not be, due to the where g.Email not in (select Email from matchedEmails) clause.

Comment: Gosh ! That was ABC. Thanks for spotting that.